# How can I tell a form not to dispose a particular control when it closes?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to write a function for my subclassed form object. The function must close the form and return a control that was on that form, so I can put it on another form.

I'm having trouble preventing the control from disposing. I thought that removing it from the controls collection using this.Controls.Remove(someControl) would be enough to stop it from disposing, but it still disposes!

What else do I have to do to tell the form not to dispose my control?

Previously, I added the control to the other form before my original form closed. This seemed to stop the dispose. The code to do this is more cumbersome though, and I'd really like to simplify things by closing the original form before I add the control to the other form.

Thanks!

Comment: Is the Owner property on the control set to null before disposing of the Owning object?

Comment: what owner property? I can't find it.

Comment: Sorry I meant Parent property.

Comment: no it wasn't. removing the control from the controls collection and setting parent = null fixed my problem, thanks. If you post an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set the Parent property of the child control to null before disposing of the Parent object.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you trying to keep it from disposing? If you are no longer referencing it, then it will get disposed. So, if you keep a reference to it in your code, then that should be enough to keep it from being disposed as you are showing that you are going to use it again in the future.

Comment: It can't dispose because I just want to move it to another form. I get the can't access disposed object exception when I try to do things over on the other form.

Comment: Try adding it as a global variable in an instance class? And, inside your static class, is the reference global or inside a method?

Comment: This not to do with the managed GC resource. A Windows control is considered Unmanaged and hence you want to call "Dispose()" as soon as you don't need it. Otherwise it might eat up limited unmanaged resources like Windows Handles for indefinite amount of time.