# Why does my recursive function to inspect controls skip over every other control?

Tags: c#, recursion, user-controls

I have a custom `UserControl` (call it `viewPanel`) that displays other custom `UserControls` (`Indicators`) in a `FlowLayoutPanel` (Specifically it has nested `FlowLayoutPanels`). When I close the form holding a `viewPanel` I wish to not dispose of all of the `Controls` and sub-`Controls` within. I want to keep the `Indicators` from being disposed. (So that they can be used later).

So to fix this I have found here on SO the easiest way would be to set the `.Parent` property of the `Indicators` to `null` so that they cannot be disposed of.

To accomplish this I have made a recursive function to set the `.Parent` of a specific type of `UserControl` to `null`. It is defined as

```
public void RecursivelyNullIndicatorParents(Control inControl) 
{
    if (inControl.Controls.Count == 0)
        return;
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < inControl.Controls.Count; i++)
        {
            Control aControl = inControl.Controls[i];
            RecursivelyNullIndicatorParents(aControl);
            if (aControl is DigitalIndicator || aControl is AnalogIndicator)
            {
                aControl.Parent = null;
                Indicator aInd = (Indicator)aControl;
                Console.Out.WriteLine("Indicator BD: " + aInd.BoardNumber + 
                    " Con: " + aInd.getContact());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Though, I still retained the error I was getting that I was trying to fix with this function. So I added the `WriteLines` in there which produced this output.

```
Indicator BD: 1 Con: 1
Indicator BD: 1 Con: 3
Indicator BD: 1 Con: 5
Indicator BD: 1 Con: 7
Indicator BD: 1 Con: 9
Indicator BD: 1 Con: 11
Indicator BD: 1 Con: 13
... // More output, same pattern.
```

Then I decided to comment out the nulling of the `.Parent` (`//aControl.Parent = null;`) which produced this output

```
Indicator BD: 1 Con: 1
Indicator BD: 1 Con: 2
Indicator BD: 1 Con: 3
Indicator BD: 1 Con: 4
Indicator BD: 1 Con: 5
Indicator BD: 1 Con: 6
Indicator BD: 1 Con: 7
Indicator BD: 1 Con: 8
Indicator BD: 1 Con: 9
Indicator BD: 1 Con: 10
Indicator BD: 1 Con: 11
Indicator BD: 1 Con: 12
Indicator BD: 1 Con: 13
... // More output, same pattern.
```

Which is more in line with what is on the `viewPanel` itself

[image: viewPanel Control]

So my question is, why would my recursive function above end up only getting ahold of every other `Control` when the `.Parents` are nulled?

***EDIT:*** Here is a reference post I was reading to come up with this idea. [How can I tell a form not to dispose a particular control when it closes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9628506/how-can-i-tell-a-form-not-to-dispose-a-particular-control-when-it-closes)

Comment: Surely you're solving the wrong problem - should you not be recursively visiting the controls and capturing the Indicator information in some form so that control disposal can proceed as normal (rather than this convoluted workaround which is based on some side-effect)?

Comment: When you say `aControl.Parent = null` it will remove `aControl` from it's parent's controls collection. So if its parent involves in this recursion for loop is not going to perform what you expect.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I am not trying to collect the `Indicator` controls, (this is already done, they are managed by the MDIParent of the `viewPanel`) I just want to be able to dispose of `viewPanel` and not the controls.

Comment: You are modifying the Controls collection by setting the Parent to null.  So in effect you'll skip every odd-numbered control.  You'll have to iterate backwards to avoid this problem.  Do note that this is also a *very* nasty resource leak, calling a control's Dispose() method is a rock-hard requirement when you remove it yourself from its Parent's Controls collection.

Comment: @HansPassant But what if I do not want to dispose of the control yet? I have references to the controls in a MDIParent so that I can display them on other forms at later times. When this MIDParent is closed then I will dispose of the controls fully.

Comment: That's okay, as long as you *eventually* dispose it.  Just keep in mind that automatic disposal no longer works when a control doesn't have a parent.

Comment: @HansPassant It works perfectly iterating backwards, write up a small answer and I'll accept it. // Thanks for the heads up too!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    aControl.Parent = null;
```

That's the exact equivalent to calling inControl.Controls.Remove(aControl).  Necessarily so, the control cannot be part of the parent's Controls collection anymore.  What you did not count on is that this also modifies the collection your are iterating with the for(;;) loop.  Something that normally generates an exception in .NET if you use foreach, unfortunately not for the ControlsCollection class or when you use for(;;).

The side-effect is that your code will skip controls, the control *after* aControl does not get iterated by your for(;;) loop.  Fixing this requires iterating the Controls collection backwards:

```
    for (int i = inControl.Controls.Count-1; i >= 0; i--)
```

Be very, *very* careful with code like this.  The controls you remove this way are reparented to the hidden "parking window", a temporary home that keeps the control window alive.  Ready to be moved to another parent.  If that does not happen then you have a *very* nasty resource leak in your program, one that the garbage collector cannot fix.  Calling the Control.Dispose() method is *not* optional, very unusual in .NET.

Keep yourself honest by checking for these leaks, you can see them in Task Manager.  View + Select Columns and tick USER Objects.  Pretty likely to be necessary, the recursive removal makes it very difficult to find these controls back later so you can properly dispose them.

Comment: a `for(;;)` loop over a collection wouldn't normally generate an exception - `ControlsCollection` is not unusual here - they're not using the `IEnumerable` interface so the collection doesn't know that it's currently being iterated over.

Comment: "Who" re-parents the `Controls` to the "parking window"? Why does the `Control` need to be kept "alive", what does it mean for it to be kept "alive"?

Comment: The Winforms plumbing does.  Keeping the native window for a client control alive instead of destroying it and re-creating it avoids several awkward problems related to .NET not having perfect knowledge of the state of a window.  This happens a lot more often than meets the eye, just changing the ShowInTaskbar property of a form for example requires completely re-creating the outer window.  The client controls sail through it unscathed thanks to the parking window.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. // So as long as I have a reference of these `Controls` I am nulling the paretns of somewhere, and I later `.Dispose()` of them, I will avoid a memory leak?

Comment: Time to stop asking for a warranty, I'd say.  You have everything you need to know, I was quite explicit about how you double-check your assumptions.

Comment: I was just trying to make sure I understand what you are telling me, you made it seem very important I understand, so I am making it a point to do so. Thank you, I understand.